# How to know if my app is authorized with FacebookSDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, uiview

Hi i have integrated my Facebook login in my app and everything works well. But issue is i have a registration form which must be shown when the user authorizes the app with Facebook for the first time(upto this it works well) . But when i again launch the app and login with the Facebook, the form is shown but i don't want this to be shown, instead it should direct to my Home view. How to achieve this any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this :[image: set your app info.plist file which is available at supporting folder]

```
-(void)Fb_Login
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             else if(session.isOpen)
             {
                 [self Fb_Login];
             }

         }];
        return;
    }



    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture,id,birthday,email,name,gender" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
             {
                 //NSDictionary *dictionary;
                 if([result objectForKey:@"data"])
                     dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[(NSArray *)[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
                 else
                     dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

                 app.fb_image_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=200&height=200",[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];
                 [app.fb_image_url retain];

                 Url_Image_social = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=200&height=200",[dictionary objectForKey:@"id"]]];
                 [Url_Image_social retain];



                 user_email = [dictionary objectForKey:@"email"];
                 [dictionary retain];

                 app.accessTokan = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];

                 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
                 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",app.accessTokan]]];
                 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                 NSError *error;
                 NSURLResponse *response;
                 NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                 NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                 fb_dict = [str JSONValue];
                 [fb_dict retain];
                 [str release];

                 if([user_email isEqualToString:@"null"] || [user_email isEqual:[NSNull null]] || !user_email)
                 {
                     NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[fb_dict objectForKey:@"first_name"],[fb_dict objectForKey:@"last_name"]];

                     user_email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@facebook.com",strName];
                     [user_email retain];
                 }
                 else
                 {     
                   //direct where ever you want 
                 }


             }
         }
     }];

}
```

Comment: how to know whether app is already authorized with Facebook??

Comment: check and set your bundle  identifier ,

Comment: else if(session.isOpen)
             {
          @that Point we can say that the person is auth with facebook
             }@FionaShoff